# Mongo full text search doesn't find

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I'm trying to implement full text search in my Mongo database. It's a database of audio tracks metadata. I wan't to search by `artistName` and `title` of a `track`. I have these records in the `tracks` collection (showing only important fields):

```
db.tracks.find({},{artistName: 1, title: 1})
{ "_id" : "A10328E00047516670", "artistName" : "Tapani Kansa", "title" : "Tuulia" }
{ "_id" : "A10328E00047516661", "artistName" : "Tapani Kansa", "title" : "Rakkautemme valssi" }
{ "_id" : "A10328E0004751669W", "artistName" : "Tapani Kansa", "title" : "Täysikuu" }
{ "_id" : "A10328E0004751668Y", "artistName" : "Tapani Kansa", "title" : "Muista minua" }
```

I've created the text index on this collection:

```
db.tracks.createIndex({artistName: 'text', title: 'text', lyrics: 'text'})
```

But when I try to search the tracks, no results are returned:

```
rs-ds047345:PRIMARY> db.tracks.find({$text: {$search: 'Tapani'}}).size()
0
rs-ds047345:PRIMARY> db.tracks.find({$text: {$search: 'Rakkautemme valssi'}}).size()
0
```

I accidentally noticed, that when I crop some letters from the end of the searched word, I'm starting to get some results... so full text search somehow works, just not in way I would like and expect.

```
db.tracks.find({$text: {$search: 'Tapa'}}).size()
12
rs-ds047345:PRIMARY> db.tracks.find({$text: {$search: 'Rakkaute'}}).size()
1
```

Could someone please tell me, how can I search the database using full words, or what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried that on MongoDB versions 3.0.8 and 3.2.1

Comment: hmm, did you tried with index per field approach?

Comment: No, I didn't... but according the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) there is a restriction of only one text index per collection and I need to index more fields in the collection.

Comment: It could be language related? maybe try setting the language to 'none', and see if that helps.
language info: 
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/text-search-languages/#text-search-languages

Comment: I've tried `> db.tracks.find({$text: {$search: 'Blueberry', $language: 'none'}})` and still no results. I also recreated index with default_language: 'none' and again, no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was in the documents stored in database. I didn't noticed that they contains a field named `language`, which changes full text search behaviour, although I tried to disable word stemming by by setting `language: 'none'` in index and queries.

When I renamed the `language` field to a different name, the full text search started to work exactly as I expect.

Answer (score 1):

according to spec -

> For case insensitive and diacritic insensitive text searches, the
>   $text operator matches on the complete stemmed word. So if a document
>   field contains the word blueberry, a search on the term blue will not
>   match. However, blueberry or blueberries will match.

what I will suggest is normal index and a regex search

> ---

```
 db.tracks.createIndex({"artistName": 1})
 db.tracks.createIndex({ "title" : 1})
 db.tracks.createIndex({ "lyrics": 1})

db.tracks.find({artistName:"/Tap/[0-10]"}).explain()
```

the square bracket will force index scan for regex instead of colscan

was testing on 3.0.6 and 3.2.3 with no luck :(

Comment: I'm gonna use regex search in case there won't be any other way, but I would really prefer to use full text search, because it perfectly fits my needs and should be easy to use. But it simply doesn't work according the documentation for me... 
I created new record with `title: 'blueberry'`
Standard find `> db.tracks.find({title: 'blueberry'}).size()` returns 1
But `db.tracks.find({$text: {$search: 'blueberry'}}).size()` => 0
`db.tracks.find({$text: {$search: 'blueberries'}}).size()` => 0
db.tracks.find({$text: {$search: 'blue'}}).size() => 0

Comment: db.tracks.createIndex({"artistName": "text", "title" : "text", "lyrics": "text"},{ default_language: "english" }) such index will allow search for blueberries and blueberry.